# С какого именно iPhone пользователь зашёл на сайт?

Tags: javascript

Ребят, нужна либо библиотека либо какая нибудь API(если такие существуют) для проверки с какого именно iPhone пользователь сидит на сайте, что бы скрывать или открывать соответствующие блоки контента и скрипта.
Буду благодарен за советы кто знает какие либо библиотека или плагины:)

Comment: Поищите по запросу "How to Precisely Detect the Device Model of Your Website’s Visitors With JavaScript"

К примеру

https://theapicompany.com/blog/device-model-detection/

Comment: огромная благодарочка)